# Is there a way to give curly braces to a bash script as command line arguments in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, arguments, command-line-arguments

I want to give a map-like structure as an argument to a bash script. I tried below methods, and they are working.

```
1. bash src.sh b:\{x:1,y:2}
```

```
2. bash src.sh b:'{x:1,y:2}' 
   "{}" also works
```

Above the first method somehow mess up when I use the command inside another script with possible line breaks inside the braces  (`\`).

```
bash src.sh b:\{x:1,\
    y:2}

y:2} part is missing
```

The second method is somewhat fine but it contains the `\` inside the argument when the line break is inside quotes `''`

```
bash src.sh b:'{x:1,\
    y:2}'

argument will be b:{a:1,\ b:2}
```

Why can't I give `{}` directly to a bash script? Is there a better way to do give `{}` or completely new way to give a map-like structure as above.

Comment: There are a number of characters that the shell will treat as special on the command line, including braces, spaces, and newlines. Generally, you need to either quote arguments that contain special characters, or escape the characters to prevent their special meaning. But you generally shouldn't quote *and* escape (with some exceptions). Also, inside the script, you should put put double-quotes around parameter and variable references (e.g. `"$1"` instead of just `$1`) for similar reasons (again, there are some exceptions).

Answer (score 4):

> Why can't I give `{}` directly to a bash script? Is there a better way to do give `{}` or completely new way to give a map-like structure as above.

Neither `{` nor `}` is treated in a special way by [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) when given as arguments to a command (unless you are unfortunate and happen to combine them to form a [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) or [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)). In your case, they are just plain characters in a string - but to avoid any future hazzle, consider surrounding the argument(s) with `'` to avoid string interpolation.

Given this script:

```
for var in "$@"
do
    echo ">$var<"
done
```

and this input

```
b:\{x:1,\
    y:2}
```

you get this output

```
>b:{x:1,<
>y:2}<
```

The reason why the first part is in `$1` and the second part is in `$2` is because there are spaces in front of `y` so the normal argument splitting comes into play. The newline does not matter in this case (it's not a part of the string). If you give this input instead:

```
b:\{x:1,\
y:2}
```

You'll get this output:

```
>b:{x:1,y:2}<
```

If you'd like to concatenate all the arguments into one, just use `"$@"`:

```
var="$@"    # or just  var=$@
```

Comment: _Neither { nor } is treated in a special way_ - I wouldn't say that. The `{..}` is a special command grouping construct in bash, that tries to run the command in same shell. That's the reason with `\{..}` the the command grouping is not expanded, because \ is one form of shell quote that is preventing it

Comment: @Inian True. Updated.

Comment: @Inian Both **{** and **}** are reserved words rather than operators though. To be treated specially they must occur as separate words. However pointing out that they are also used for constructing brace expansions would be beneficial.

Comment: @oguzismail: Agreed.

Comment: @oguzismail More caveats added :-D

Comment: @Ted thanks for the answer. Can't guarantee that the user of the script will use the arguments with the no space like break. Can I enforce user to use quotes for the map argument (`bash src.sh b:'{x:1,y:2}'`)  and I can remove possible ```\```s from the string assuming it won't contain any arguments with ```\``` in them.

Comment: @NalakaRajamanthri You are welcome! If the users are going to use the CLI and supply this kind of information they must have some `bash` knowledge or else this will be painful. Suggest to the users that they put `'` around the complete argument(s): `'b:{x:1,y:2}'` which will work for as long as you do not need the actual `'` sign in the data. If you do, then the users will need to know how to escape that character.